# Замена символов в строке

Tags: c++, парсер, символы, замена

У меня есть строка: `"''Start''"`.
После всех действий над ней, должно получиться: `"Start"`. Т.е удаляются все символы `"`,  а затем все пары символов `''` заменяются на `"`.
Удаляю из нее все символы `"`:
`result.erase(std::remove(result.begin(), result.end(), '"' ), result.end());`

Затем нужно заменить все пары символов `''` на `"`:
`replace(result.begin(), result.end(), "\'\'", "\"");`

Выдает ошибку следующую ошибку:

```
tools/data_parser.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
tools/data_parser.cpp:21:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘replace(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator, const char [3], const char [2])’
  replace(result.begin(), result.end(), "\'\'", "\"");
                                                    ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:62:0,
                 from tools/data_parser.cpp:7:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:4233:5: note: candidate: template<class _FIter, class _Tp> void std::replace(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&, const _Tp&)
     replace(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:4233:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tools/data_parser.cpp:21:52: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘const _Tp’ (‘char [3]’ and ‘char [2]’)
  replace(result.begin(), result.end(), "\'\'", "\"");
```

Я так понимаю, что `std::replace` заменяет только один символ на другой. Как заменить пару символов? Компилирую так: `g++-5 -std=c++11 cfg_parser.cpp -o cfg_parser`

Comment: Позвольте поинтересоваться: если уж вы пишете на C++, зачем вам ручное распределение памяти с `const char *` и связанные с ним проблемы?

Comment: А `strlen(result.c_str())` — ?

Comment: Я только изучаю `C++`. `strlen()` сейчас заменю на `size()`. Спасибо за поправку.

Comment: VladD, а что использовать, вместо `const char *`, не подскажите?

Comment: Вы лучше примеры *что должно получаться* из входных строк подробно напишите (а то разбирать логику по коду лень).

Comment: @Eanmos: `std::string` везде

Comment: Если запустить программу так: `./cfg_parser data.gd [main-menu-start-game-button]`, то дожно вывести: `"Start"`, т.е удаляются все символы `"` из строки, а потом нужно заменить пару символов `''` на `"`, что я и не могу сделать.

Comment: @Eanmos: Сишные строки (`char*`) требуют хорошего умения работать с памятью и понимания указателей, что для новичков обычно тяжело. Когда вы освоитесь с языком, обязательно выучите и поймите сишные строки. Но лучше не сначала, они сложные.

Comment: @Eanmos: Не, не так. Никому не охота продираться сквозь логику программы. Уменьшите программу до одной неправильно работающей строчки. Чтение из файла важно для проблемы, или если вместо файла подставить константу, то тоже работает? Выясните!

Comment: @Eanmos: А не нужно ли `result.replace` вместо просто `replace`?

Comment: @VlaD, при исполнении выдает: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_replace
Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вы можете выполнить задачу следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string s( "\"''Start''\"" );

    std::cout << '[' << s << ']' << std::endl;

    s.erase( std::remove( s.begin(), s.end(), '"' ), s.end() );

    for ( std::string::size_type n = 0; ( n = s.find( "''", n ) ) != std::string::npos; ++n )
    {
        s.replace( n, 2, 1, '"' );
    }

    std::cout << '[' << s << ']' << std::endl;
}
```

Программа имеем следующий вывод на консоль:

```
["''Start''"]
["Start"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Просто, быстро и (надеюсь) надежно

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *
replq (char *str)
{
  int i, j;

  for (i = j = 0; str[i]; i++) 
    if (str[i] != '"') {
      if (str[i] == '\'' && str[i + 1] == '\'') {
        str[j++] = '"';
        i++;
      } else
        str[j++] = str[i];
    }
  str[j] = 0;

  return str;
}


int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char str[1000];

  while (fgets(str, 1000, stdin))
    puts(replq(str));

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

По поводу Си -- конечно это Си (но g++ признает код своим, т.е. крестовым).

Answer (score 2):

`std::replace` действительно заменяет лишь символы.

Вам нужно воспользоваться `string::replace`.

```
string haystack = "''text''";
string needle = "''";
size_t pos;
while ((pos = haystack.find(needle)) != haystack.npos)
    haystack.replace(pos, pos + needle.length(), "\"");
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/zxa0Rn

Впрочем, это по сути не отличается от варианта @Vlad from Moscow

Answer (score 0):

```
/***********************************************************
* Method:    fn_Replace
* Description  Замена одного символа в строке на один символ или строку 
* Returns:   void
* Parameter: wstring & ws - исходная строка
* Parameter: const wchar_t wchF - один заменяемый символ
* Parameter: LPCTSTR wchR   - замена, символ или строка символов 
************************************************************/
void fn_Replace(wstring& ws, const wchar_t wchF, LPCTSTR wchR)
{
    size_t sz = ws.size();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
    {
        if(ws[i] != wchF)  continue;
        else ws.replace(i,1,wchR);
    }
}
```